# Help Troubleshoot Codes

Tags: apex

I can't figure out why this code will not update all three records from the SOQL statement.  There is only 1 record updated and the two records are ignored.

In Developer Console:

```
List<Business__c> defaultList = [Select Id, Name, Business_Name__c, Status__c From Business__c];
system.debug(defaultList.size());//This shows there are 3 records
Business__c[] defaultUpdate = New Business__c[]{};
for (Business__c d : defaultList){           
    //Default Values
    defaultUpdate.add(New Business__c(ID = d.ID, Update_Name__c = d.Business_Name__c, Update_Status__c = d.Status__c));          
}
database.Update(defaultUpdate, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use Database.update, you need to check the results of the DML as no exception will be thrown if an error (like a validation rule error)

```
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(defaultUpdate,false); // allow partial succcesses
for (Integer i = 0; i < srList.size(); i++)
  if (!srList[i].isSuccess()) 
   // do something - look at getErrors().
```

If you used:

```
 update defaultUpdate;
```

then any errors in the update will be thrown as an exception unless you wrap (as you should) the DML with a try-catch block